# Uncaught ReferenceError: piwikTracker is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, matomo

Piwik tracker allows custom tracking as such:

```
jQuery('div.orange').click(function() {
    piwikTracker.trackGoal(3); // Track click on this hitarea
});
```

In my WordPress environment, I'm loading this jQuery in a script separate from the piwik.js script for obvious reasons.

In Chrome, I receive the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: piwikTracker is not defined

on the script that I'm using custom tracking.

Is there a way I can define the function before calling the event handler function? Why only Chrome?

EDIT

I checked out the piwik php script that loads the JavaScript and it's actually loading the script in the footer. The function that calls for the custom tracking is loaded in the header. Does this matter? Do scripts in the header always get loaded before the footer?

Comment: Have you verified in the "Network" tab that the script is being loaded?

Comment: just did and it's not! It does in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Asynchronous tracking solves this problem in an elegant way:

```
var _paq = _paq || [];
_paq.push(['trackGoal', 3]);
```

If piwik was loaded before, this automatically sends the Goal Request. If piwik is loaded after it, it is only an array that will be processed once piwik is loaded!

See [documentation](http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/) on how to set up asynchronous tracking, it will be the default method for Piwik 1.11.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Where you put the script in the page matters. Thinking that, when the browser interprets the page, it will read the head first, and then body. For your case, you better check the DOMReady and the object piwikTracker first.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.orange').click(function() {
        if (piwikTracker) {
            piwikTracker.trackGoal(3); // Track click on this hitarea
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Piwik.js is loading in the footer so that's why the function isn't loading. I tried specifying that the script load in the footer but that created a white screen of death.

Comment: The jquery is in the ready handler but I still get the error. I think I'm specifying the wrong dependent for the script to load. I'm not sure exactly which script I need to depend on for Piwik and the wp-piwik plugin.

Comment: DOM:ready is not enough, it should wait until window:load: `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in `ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
  jQuery('div.orange').click(function() {
    piwikTracker.trackGoal(3); // Track click on this hitarea
  });
});
```

Or `onload` event whichever works:

```
window.onload = function() {
  jQuery('div.orange').click(function() {
     piwikTracker.trackGoal(3); // Track click on this hitarea
  });
}
```